# Bring Javascript values up one level - make key:object:key just object:key

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript object:

```
{"475":{"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"475"},
 "512":{"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"512"}}
```

I'd like to remove the '475' and '512' keys so the output would be:

```
{
     {"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"475"},
     {"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"512"}
}
```

Is that possible in Javascript?

I have tried several methods but am unable to get it to work.

Comment: You can't have values without keys in an object, unless you want the top-level to be an array?

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you attempted, as the other comment mentions what you are looking for is an array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
obj = Object.keys(your_JSON_OBJ).map((key)=>{
  return your_JSON_OBJ[key]
}
```

this will return you an array of your child objects. You will not be able to move them into an object with our the structure of an array because you have no "key" portion of the "key:value" outside of your child elements now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an array of objects like suggested in the comments you could use `Object.values()`.

```js
var obj = {
  "475":{"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"475"},
  "512":{"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"512"}
}

console.log(Object.values(obj))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

let a = {"475":{"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"475"},
 "512":{"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"512"}};

 console.log(a);

let myArray = [];  
for (var property in a) {
    myArray.push( a[property]);
}

 console.log(myArray);


</script>
```